# Should I upgrade kernel after installing Ubuntu 16.04 (performance/freezing)?

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel, performance

I've installed **Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS** alongside Windows 10 yesterday. My PC: **Aspire-VN7-591G**.

```
>>> uname -r
>>> 4.4.0-83-generic
```

At the beginning everything seemed to work good, without freezing but today **Ubuntu** started freezing. Especially Firefox videos and even pages without videos, or folders sometimes aren't opened immediately.

Today, Django server and Scrapy with Selenium project is running on this PC and I'm experiencing huge freezing very frequently. For example search window took about 10 seconds to open.

I've done `apt-get update` and then `upgrade`, installed `indicator-cpufreq` and set to performance and couple of other things. Ubuntu still doesn't work smoothly.

I've read that I could upgrade **kernel** but I'm not sure if it's a good idea and if I've chosen correct version.

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.12.1/

Can I install this kernel and will this improve performance? 
Are there some disadvantages?

**EDIT:**

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7,7G        6,3G        231M        591M        1,2G        568M
Swap:          7,9G        1,5G        6,4G
```

Comment: What's the output of `free -h`?

Comment: @George I've added the output of free -h at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You are low of RAM. Kernel is not related.